# Headcount over a period

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I need to provide a avg headcount of the total population in my data base and a avg headcount of people in sick leave in the last 6 months aggregated by country , and building.
But it seems that I am getting duplicated records.

```
WITH temp as (SELECT

       emp.country,
       emp.building,
       emp.status,

       sum(1)    AS hc,

       CASE
           WHEN status::text = 'L'::character varying::text THEN sum(1)
           ELSE 0
           END    AS loa
FROM employees_table emp
         LEFT JOIN booker.o_reporting_days rd ON 1 = 1
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND emp.status::text = 'A'::character varying::text 
  AND rd.calendar_day >= emp.hr_begin_dt
  AND rd.calendar_day <= emp.hr_end_dt
  AND emp.country IN (SELECT country_long_code
    FROM static_tbl.aa_included_countries)
  AND emp.job_level_name = '1'
  AND trunc(rd.calendar_day) BETWEEN '2022-09-01' AND '2022-03-31'
  AND emp.employee_class_name::text !~~* '%vendor%'::character varying::text
GROUP BY 1,2,3)

SELECT tp.country ,
       tp.building_code,
       avg(tp.hc) as avg_hc,
       avg(tp.loa) as avg_loa
    FROM temp tp    
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Comment: Can you possibly simplify your query to only contain enough to demonstrate the problem (eg remove WHERE statements that are not relevant to the problem) and please show sample data from the table(s) so that we can attempt to reproduce your problem.